# How can I change the component of a registry key in Installshield?

Tags: windows-installer, installation, components, installshield

I have to put a registry key in another component from it's original.

How can I make this step without exporting it an importing back in the other component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

InstallShield has a view called "Direct Editor". This is where you can see the underlying windows installer table data / relationships.  You can go to the registry table, find the row you are interested in and then update the Component_ column (There's even a drop down) and associate that entry to a different component.

You don't mention if you are using major upgrades or minor upgrades.  Please realize that certain things are not possible in Windows Installer so thoroughly test your install, upgrade, uninstall.